# Questions with new activity shows old answers made community wiki

Tags: bug, community-wiki, live-refresh, homepage

I leave a browser tab open on the Server Fault homepage. This afternoon after being away for a short while I saw the notification:

[image: 5 questions with new activity]

When I clicked it, all I saw were old questions.

[image: A bunch of old posts]

On checking a few of them, I found that all of the questions had an old answer that had recently been made community wiki.

When I reloaded the home page, all of them were gone, leading me to believe that old answers made CW shouldn't appear on the home page.

[image: No new activity after hitting Reload]

So, I suspect that either these old posts being made CW should be appearing on the cached home page, or we should not be notified of them via the websocket.

Comment: Also, shouldn't posts only become CW due to some *other* activity?

Comment: @Arjan Anyone can mark their own _answer_ CW.

Comment: I think what @Arjan is saying is that marking an answer community wiki necessarily involves *editing*. And edits always "bump" the associated question. That's by design.

Comment: @Cody not in this case, Michael is up to something here. See [this](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=active&q=%22iptables%20rules%20order%22%20is%3aquestion) - the last activity is May 11, even though the user wikified his answer [12 hours ago](http://serverfault.com/posts/506910/revisions). Also note there's no hint for this in the [user activity](http://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain?tab=activity&sort=all). This leads me to believe that such action only add **post notice** rather then full revision. No revision likely means no bump and no edit.